# ms access match on first characters fields are unequal length and text changes after nth position

Tags: ms-access

I have two columns with characters in each that match until a point and then the remaining characters don't match and the strings are often of unequal length.   The position of the character where they no longer match varies but is typically after the 10th character.

I'll be glad to post a small example...is there a way to format it so it's readable on here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the left function to match the columns.

Build a query containing your two columns and then add expressions to that query that find the matches up to different lengths.

In the SQL add columns;

```
IIF(Left(Column1, 1) = (Left(Column2, 1), 1, 0) AS [Char1Match], 
IIF(Left(Column1, 2) = (Left(Column2, 2), 1, 0)  AS [Char2Match], 
IIF(Left(Column1, 3) = (Left(Column2, 3), 1, 0)  AS [Char3Match] etc.
```

This will give you a series of columns in the resultant query where 1 indicates a match up to a certain number of characters and 0 no match. The result might look like

```
Column1    Column2    Char1Match   Char2Match   Char3Match
abcdef     axxx       1            0            0
abcdef     abxx       1            1            0
abcdef     abcx       1            1            1
```

Comment: Ok, I see.   Thank you very much, I will try it and let you know

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost.   I know the query design grid.   Often I will build in the grid, then switch to sql view and struggle until I solve the problem.   Do I compare the columns in the two tables, then add this in the sql?

Comment: Still trying.   I think I understand but the syntax isn't working.   Can you spot the problem here?          Expr1: IIf(Left[tbl_Ahri_Unique_Records]![Ahri_Full_Pn],1) =(left[AS_Furnace]![UnitModel], 1),1,0) As[match]    Thanks

Comment: If you're using the grid add a column like this - Char1Match:IIF(Left(Column1, 1) = (Left(Column2, 1), 1, 0)

Comment: Thanks for the help.   I can't get it to work.   The columns are in two different tables.  Is this a problem?  My example above has been altered, checked and rechecked and I get errors.   I'll try to get examples of errors but I'm done for now.

Comment: Post the SQL of the query with the columns that you want to do the matching on and I'll add in a sample match column.

Comment: SELECT tbl_Ahri_Unique_Records.Ahri_Full_Pn, Gensco_Mh_Pricing.GenscoPnLessAms
FROM tbl_Ahri_Unique_Records, Gensco_Mh_Pricing;                There is no relationship link between these two tables because I think your suggested query will compare all possible combinations.   I can send clarification if needed.     Thank you very much for taking the time to help!

Comment: SELECT tbl_Ahri_Unique_Records.Ahri_Full_Pn, Gensco_Mh_Pricing.GenscoPnLessAms, IIF(Left(tbl_Ahri_Unique_Records.Ahri_Full_Pn, 1) = (Left(Gensco_Mh_Pricing.GenscoPnLessAms, 1), 1, 0) AS [Char1Match] FROM tbl_Ahri_Unique_Records, Gensco_Mh_Pricing

Comment: Thank you             I get syntax error (missing operator in query expression)     I got this often when I was trying this on my own.   I'll start researching and I'll post if I solve it.

Comment: Set up a query that just returns the two columns you need to work with - the reason that you're getting an error is that the tables in the FROM clause are not joined - and post that. I'll add in the calculated column.

Comment: Thanks Jh for all your help.    I think this is what you are looking for:       SELECT tbl_Ahri_Unique_Records.Ahri_Full_Pn, Gensco_Mh_Pricing.GenscoPn
FROM tbl_Ahri_Unique_Records, Gensco_Mh_Pricing;

Comment: That query won't work because the tables tbl_Ahri_Unique_Records and  Gensco_Mh_Pricing are not joined. Set up a query with the two tables joined and then post the SQL.

Comment: I can't join the columns because they don't match exactly.   The first 10-13 characters match, then they diverge.   There is only one best match and that one is the match that matches the most characters before they diverge.   How do I post in a table format and I'll give a clear example.  Thank you again.

Comment: You don't need to join the tables on the columns that you're running the match formula on, but the two columns need to appear in the resulting query. Can you join the tables on another column?